# How can I extend my Destruction sprees?

Tags: diablo-iii

How can I prolong my destructive rampages?  Keeping up a certain average time between smashing this or that, or getting one every few seconds?  It 'feels' different than the [massacre system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work), but that could just be me not worrying about combat.

Comment: There's also Survival, when your health drops below a certain amount (less than 10%, I believe) and you survive. Though the bonus you get is negligible.

Comment: Depends on your Hero

Answer (score 2):

Destruction sprees appear to be very similar in nature to massacre sprees.  A great place to play around is the Cemetery of the Forsaken in Act I (blow up gravestones).

From playing around with my barbarian:

- A destruction spree starts at 6 destroyed items (unless you haven't gotten that high yet)
- The spree ends if you do not destroy something within around 1.75 seconds (I'm sure I'm a bit off)
- Even if you destroy a bunch of items at once (a cluster of urns in a crypt, for example), the 1.75 second rule seems to still hold true.
- Killing monsters seems to have no prolonging effect on the spree (I got a spree notice within ~200ms of killing a mob)

**So, in order to maximize a destruction spree:**

- Make sure you're within a short distance of your next target at all times
- Plan out a path that hits as many as possible!
- Single target destructibles if you need time to move between them

*(the Cemetery of the Forsaken is a great location - there are large clusters of graves that you can travel between if you're fast - and you can easily grab the Grave Buster achievement at the same time)*

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that: if you play the Witch Doctor, there's a skill (and a rune) that looks perfect to prolong "Destruction Sprees".

The skill is **Firebomb** with the rune **Flash Fire**. 
It lanuches a molotov-cocktail-like bomb, wich (with the Flash Fire rune) bounces 6 times (smashing enemies and objects for you as you walk).

With that, i got the "**Destruction Derby**" achievement at the first try. If you need it, just go to the Cemetery of the Forsaken, and start from the northern side of the cemetary, just launch bombs and walk, if necessary, exit the cemetery gate and keep bombing.

Answer (score 0):

I found you dont have to kill the actual monsters to keep the spree going you just have to hit a monster. So if a big monster does pop up just keep attacking him. Sometimes if you miss an auto attack combo spree will end miss 2 auto attacks and its 100% over.

I would be nice to see killing spree and destruction bonuses stack so if you destroy a destructible object or hit a monster either spree would continue until you fail to hit within a certain amount of time.