# How much time do I have between events for XP bonuses?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the massacre bonus work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work)

Destruction grants you bonus XP for destroying objects and Massacre grants bonus XP for kill streaks.  How much time do I have between these events for it to count as part of the same chain?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to throw a bounty on the dup. question.

Comment: @RavenDreamer should I make a new question for Destruction, then?

Comment: I don't think so, simply because the only difference between Destruction and Massacre is the type of entity (Enemy vs. Obstacle) that's being destroyed. I'd edit the other question to include asking about destruction instead.