# How do experience bonuses work in co-op?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know *of* bonuses you can earn in Diablo 3 such as [Massacre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49545/336). It's very simple in single-player, because you're the only one doing any killing.

But what happens in co-op?

- Do all players contribute towards the same experience bonuses? I.e, if I destroy 5 barrels while my co-op buddy destroys 3 barrels, do we get an 8 item destruction bonus?
- Does each player battle out for their own bonuses and (essentially) ignore other players?
- Something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cooperative play, separate tickers happen for each party member, but you don't need to have a killing blow in order to benefit.

Massacre- This bonus counts how many monsters died during one unbroken chain of your attacks.  As long as you are damaging monsters constantly, with pauses of no more than 1 second, you will continue to stack the bonus.  When your attacks stop connecting with monsters for about a second, the system rewards you for all the monsters *you wounded*, that are currently dead.

Mighty Blow- the system counts how many monsters you wounded with one attack, that happen to be dead in the following second.

Destruction- I don't think it's possible for 2 people to simultaneously damage a barrel, since they go down in 1 hit. So, no sharing this one.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, bonus goes to the player who made the killing blow. So yes, you are battling out for your own bonus.

A buddy of mine has claimed that there is a timer, and if you damaged an enemy within x seconds of its death, it will contribute to your bonus. I however have not seen any evidence of this.