# Do I get less experience if a high-level friend accompanies me?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does experience work in groups of heroes with different levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/how-does-experience-work-in-groups-of-heroes-with-different-levels)

My friend and I both have Diablo 3, but he has more play time, and so has a much higher level. Sometimes he comes back and does the same quests I'm still on, but when he does it feels like I am getting less experience. Is this all in my head, or do I get less XP if higher-level players are in my party?

Comment: Closing my own question... Sorry I missed the existing question that covers the same topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63440/7797) by [Sean](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/21177/sean):

> There is **no party experience split**.

All members in your party will receive the same experience as long as they are within "a screen and a half" of the kill. The experience you won't receive comes from bonuses like the [Massacre bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work) or boosts from equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The lower level still receives full exp. The only issue with this is and where you may be seeing your exp going down would be becasue he is probably getting all the kills, so you are missing the massacre and other exp bonuses for killing enemies.