# Diablo 3, XP bonus due to kill chain

Tags: diablo-iii

After killing 10 enemies in Diablo 3 on Xbox One just now an "alert" popped up to tell me that (ie. 10 kills) and that I got an XP bonus of 1.5x.

Is this bonus retroactively applied to those 10 kills, or would it have applied to further kills?

It seems these alerts only pop up when I break the chain, so I think it would be strange if they tell me that I could've gotten an XP bonus on further kills so I am leaning towards retroactively applied, but I thought I'd ask just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is not retroactive.

I believe what you saw was the massacre bonus.

It is bonus xp for killing enemies in a continuous fashion. The more you kill, the bigger the chunk of bonus xp you will receive.  It is a one time bonus for the amount you kill. The longer the killing streak, the bigger the bonus.

[This question has more information on it.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work)

Comment: I think your answer is not correct. Your linked question is regarding the original D3 while this questions obviously concerns the Ultimate Evil Edition. Massacre Bonus has definitively changed in this version. And I think it IS retroactive, but I have no proof.