# Do all party members contribute to kill streaks and massacres in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do the kills via party members and temporary quest guests contribute to the numbers required by massacre and kill streak?

The one question not answered here [How does the massacre bonus work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work)

Also, do you get the exp of quest guest kills? Do they share in any of that experience?

Comment: Quest NPCs, as well as followers, are not players and do not have the notion of experince. Experience is gained by all players within a certain (large) radius of the kill - so yes, you gain experience from kills of your NPC party. As for the massacre bonus, that is pretty easy to test - just go to Normal and have your Follower kill 10 monsters. I will test myself, if no one does until the weekend.

Comment: Followers gain experience and level, and these numbers are different then yours. I gained level 15 well before my follower. Do they share in gained experience with you?  If you earned 20exp, do you and your follower both get 10 exp, or do you both get 20exp?

I think my testing shows they contribute to kill streaks, but massacres are alot harder to test.  There are two parts to that issue too, whether if a NPC kills 10 units at once, whether you get a massacre bonus, and whether  if you kill 5 units and your follower kills 5 units at the same time, whether you get the massacre bonus.

Comment: Ahhh... You are playing Diablo 3 classic, right? Without Reaper of Souls? Followers were changed in RoS to not have experince, though they did before. They do not take any experience from you (you still get 20 exp), but other than that, I don't remember much (and won't be able to test).

Comment: Ehm, "massacre" and "kill streak" are the same bonus. It should not be that hard to test, as dealing damage, even without killing, keeps it up.

Comment: @OrcJMR If I recall (and it's been a while), you would gain 20 exp and your follower would get 2 exp (an additional 10%) regardless of who got the kill.  But I think only console still sees this system, right?

Comment: @OrcJMR It is like that in D3 no matter if you have RoS or not. The need to level followers was patched out together with the RMAH.

Comment: @DeleteMe You're right, I forgot about relation of patch 2.0 and RoS.

Comment: ""massacre" and "kill streak" are the same bonus" No they are not. Kill streak is uninterrupted kills or attacks, massacre is number of enemies killed at the same time or near the same time.

Comment: I have done some more testing, it seems their kills count towards kill streaks and massacres. But I don't think their hits maintain kill streaks. With a party of 3, with follower, temp quest NPC and raven pet, if I didn't personally fight enough, they would not get kill streaks.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

I have been playing online with a few friends and due to their "power-levelling" techniques, I can hardly keep up with both in speed and damage. Basically, each person controls their own sprees, and even if you assisted in damaging the creature, unless you *killed* it, then it does not contribute to your own spree.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing this with multiple scenarios, this would be a hard one to figure out. My immediate guess would be no, because i notice generally lower massacre streaks etc when i have friends playing with me, but that could be attributed to the minions growing stronger as people join the game. Since the mobs are randomly generated, it would be hard to get two groups of the exact same size, let alone 4 different times to test for sure the effects of being alone and with a friend.